# How to open open card and verify the content inside then open the second card and verify the content and so on

Tags: automation, cypress, cypress-each

I need to open the first card and verify that everything inside matches the hashtag 'Fashion' and then do the same for the next 3 cards and then press the 'next' button and do the same for next 4 cards. how would I do it? I tried the regular way by clicking on the `element.eq(0)` and verifying everything inside and then `cy.go('back')` and so on but that's so much code duplication. how would I do it the other way?

First 4 cards:

[image: first 4 cards]

Second 4 cards:

[image: second 4 cards]

The CSS selector for all of them is the same `[class="discover-card"]`. please help:) thank you

Comment: Are you only looking to test the first and second set of 4 cards or until there no more cards?

Comment: well total amount is 12 cards so after last one I need to stop :)

Comment: Great. There is probably a request made to your server that retrieves the list of Communities to browse. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cypress's `.each()` functionality to iterate through elements with the same CSS selector.

```js
cy.get('.discover-card').each(($card, index) => {
  // cy.go('back') can cause the list to become detached, so find element by index of original list.
  cy.get('.discover-card').eq(index).click();  
  // validations after clicking the card
  // unsure on this exact function, but was provided in question
  cy.go('back').then(() => {
    // if this is the fourth item checked, we need to press the next button.
    if ((index + 1) % 4 === 0) {
      cy.get('.next-btn').click(); // this selector is the next button on the carousel
    }
  });
});
```

If the data between the cards is unique, I'd advise creating a data object you can use to store the data and reference it in your test. You can do this by having each data object have a unique key equal to the text on the card, or by storing them in an array.

```js
// unique keys
const data = { fashion: { foo: 'bar' }, beauty: { foo: 'bar2' }, ... };
// array
const data = [{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'bar2' }, ...];
...
// unique keys
cy.wrap($card).should('have.attr', 'foo', data[$card.text()].foo);
// array
cy.wrap($card).should('have.attr', 'foo', data[index].foo);
```

Comment: I would skip the `cy.go('back')` as it will reload the page and invalidate the `$list` in `.each()` (detached-from-DOM error).

Comment: Ah yeah, I haven't really ever used `cy.go('back')`. I'll update my answer to better reflect how we could use that.

Comment: Not quite what I meant - all of the `$card` would get detached as well.

Comment: That may be true, but I believe the reference to the current index is kept -- I did some light testing around this and it seems to behave fine, even when the elements become detatched (due to `cy.go('back')`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, since it kept just going back and forth :( this is some very high level coding tho

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about code duplication, put the common code in a function

```js
const expectedData [
  { index: 1, title:'Fashion', ... } // anything you want to check
  { index: 2, title:'Beauty', ... } 
]

const checkCard = (cardIndex) => {
  const data = expectedData[cardIndex]
  cy.get('.discover-card')
    .should('contain', data.title)
    .click()                  // open card

  // test card internals

}

Cypress._.times(3, (pageNo) => {  // loop 3 times between pages
  Cypress._.times(4, (cardNo) => {  // loop 4 times for cards
    const cardIndex = ((pageNo+1) * (cardNo+1)) -1
    checkCard(cardIndex)
    cy.go.back()                // revert to menu
  })
  cy.get('.next-btn').click()
})
```